# manage the top navigation via a custom list?

Tags: list, navigation

Is it possible for contributors to manage the top navigation via a custom list? So basically when a sub-site or page is created the user has the ability to assign where it goes via the list. If so can anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom SitemapProvider.
Look at the following code samples:

- [Writing a Custom Navigation Provider for MOSS](http://faraz-khan.blogspot.com/2008/11/writing-custom-navigation-provider-for.html)
- [MOSS custom navigation provider for left nav](http://faraz-khan.blogspot.com/2009/05/moss-custom-navigation-provider-for.html)

Those posts are written for MOSS 2007 - but the workmethod stays the same in SPS2010.

Comment: +1 to you, I didn't notice you posted while I was typing up mine.

Comment: +1 for you 2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement a custom site map provider.  You can have it pull data from just about anywhere, including a list.  There are numerous examples available all over the web on how to implement custom navigation with custom providers.

Including here in SPSE:

[Cross Site Collection Navigation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21445/cross-site-collection-navigation)

[Menu Navigation in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13162/menu-navigation-in-sharepoint-2010)

via goole below:

http://www.google.com/search?q=SharePoint+Custom+Navigation+Providers

You may find this post is pretty close to what you are trying to do:

http://faraz-khan.blogspot.com/2008/11/writing-custom-navigation-provider-for.html

I would also go over the MSDN Navigation sections, it covers in detail more option as well as when and why you would extend from asp.net provider vs. SharePoint :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558975.aspx