# Collapsable menu in place of quick launch for a subsite

Tags: web-part, quick-launch

I have to create a collapsable menu for a subsite, which replaces the default menu in Quick Launch.

And, the items of the menu are dynamic on the basis of content in list and lookups.

I have searched online and found solutions related to DataView web parts, SharePoint designer and xslt.

like: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/01/15/a-drop-down-menu-the-sharepoint-way/

But, I have to add the web part through code. And i also intent to use the default CSS already defined for that site.

Many thanks, your replies would help me alot :)

Comment: any pointers would be greatly appreciated. As of now I have no idea on how to move forward with this :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create a custom sitemap provider.
Similar post:
[manage the top navigation via a custom list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/manage-the-top-navigation-via-a-custom-list/22011#22011)

The collapse effect can be achieved with some jQuery.